# Help in identifying an object

Tags: translation

I have an item with Chinese writing on it.  Can anyone help me identify it / how old it is?

any help would be greatly appreciated...

Jonah

[image]

Comment: Ancient Japanese money: 札所 龍見四郎右衛門・酒屋宗八郎・的場長兵衛

Answer (score 1):

[札所](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%9C%AD%E6%89%80-124946) is a Japanese term

> 札所: 仏教の霊場の称。巡礼者が参詣のしるしとして札を受けたりおさめたりするところ
>
> The name of a Buddhist sanctuary. Where pilgrims accept **tags** as signs of pilgrimage.

和州, 芝村  is a place's name, but [和州](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C%E5%B7%9E) in Google search doesn't seem to  exist in today's China

The names at the bottom are all Japanese names

You should post this question at the Japanese StackExchange section

Answer (score 1):

[芝村](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8A%9D%E6%9D%91%E8%97%A9) (Shibamura) is an Edo-era Japanese feudal domain, which is located in 大和国 ([Yamato Province](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamato_Province)), which also known as 和州 (Washū).